# Add multiple sheets in existing excel using pandas in Python

Tags: python, excel, hive, pyodbc

My code is reading SQL queries from text file and executing them one by one in python.I am trying save result of queries in the same excel but in different tabs/worksheets

```
import pyodbc as hive
import pandas as pd

filename =r'C:\Users\krkg039\Desktop\query.txt'
fd=open(filename,'r')

sqlFile=fd.read()

fd.close()

# all SQL commands (split on ';')
sqlCommands = sqlFile.split(';')

# Execute every command from the input file
for command in sqlCommands:
    try:
        con = hive.connect("DSN=SFO-LG", autocommit=True)
        df = pd.read_sql(command,con)
        print(df)
        print(command)
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Result.xlsx')
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Test',index=False)
        writer.save()
    except:
        print("Command skipped: ")
```

In the code I want to python to add sheets to existing excel for each SQL queries executed.

Basically python should NOT replace my excel every time

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this is exactly the problem but I think if you take the 
`writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Result.xlsx')` 
out of the for loop then you're not re-defining it every time.
Also make the name of the sheets dynamic with the loop so you're not over-writing it.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Result.xlsx')
for command in sqlCommands:
    try:
        con = hive.connect("DSN=SFO-LG", autocommit=True)
        df = pd.read_sql(command,con)
        print(df)
        print(command)
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Test'+command,index=False)
        writer.save()
    except:
        print("Command skipped: ")
```

Comment: ... probably don't need to have the `.connect` inside the loop either.

Comment: @Gord Thompson Got it.Putting Hive.connect before the for loop worked.Thanks